# UITableViewRowAction was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to upgrade code of my project and found this warning

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: deleteActionTitle) { [unowned self] (_, indexPath) in
        //code you want to execute        }
    return [deleteRowAction]
}
```

Comment: First SO search result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578303/1187415.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: deleteActionTitle) {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        //Code I want to do here 
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}
```

Comment: So it's clear since it's inferred from the answer, `UIContextualAction` is a drop in replacement for `UITableViewRowAction`. So, the migration ends up being something like:

1. Add `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` delegate method.
2. Change references to `UITableViewRowAction` to `UIContextualAction`. The initializer will be slightly different in ObjC.
3. Pass the actions array to the `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` creation method instead of directly returning it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `UISwipeActionsConfiguration` over `UITableViewRowAction` such as

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

  return UISwipeActionsConfiguration()
}
```